# How to suppress console output when assigning property value in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set the value of the InnerText property on an XML node. I.E.

```
$b = $a.CreateElement("MyNode");
$b.InnerText = "MyValue";
```

This works, but generates console output. It writes MyValue to the console.

I can change it to this:

```
$b = $a.CreateElement("MyNode");
$b.InnerText = "MyValue" | Out-Null;
```

However, in this case the value of InnerText is not set to MyValue.

How do I set the value of InnerText without writing to the console?

Comment: Your first code snippet does not produce console output. The second code snippet does not set the inner text of the node b/c you discard the value by piping it into `Out-Null`. Please create a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem you're facing, then [edit] your question and copy/paste that code along with any error you're getting from that code.

Comment: I only get involuntary output when using the method AppendChild...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to prevent output:

Direct the output to the `$null` variable:

```
($b.InnerText = "MyValue") | Out-Null
```

Store the output in the `$null` variable:

```
$null = ($b.InnerText = "MyValue")
```

Make the data type of the output `[void]`:

```
[void]$b.InnerText = "MyValue"
```

Use `(1 -eq 1)` to produce output if `$b.InnerText = "MyValue"` doesn't work for you.

Comment: Using the InnerText method doesn't produce any output for me. Using AppendChild however do...

Comment: @Dennis for me neither. I used `(1 -eq 1)` to generate some output. However there are thousands of actions that generate output that nobody needs or wants. These are just three of the most common ways to get rid of some output.

Comment: Yes, but your suggestion doesn’t work as a solution in this very case because the question doesn’t replicate the issue… The example has no output to hide.